# Python,Sorting a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working on a dict in python. I am trying to sort it out alphabetically and split it to look slightly better. 
Here is the code I have so far in the dictonatary.

```
authorentry = {'author':  name, 'date': datef , 'path': path_change , 'msg' : xmlMsgf }           
if not name in author:
    author[ name ] = []

author[ name ].append( authorentry )       

if not authorentry in author.items():
    author['author'] = [authorentry]

print sorted (author.keys()), sorted (author.values())
```

Now what i want it to do is print out the dict in a sorted order based on the author and the date. and also to split it and modified it so it doesn't have all those commas and 'u's if that is possible. Any ideas on how to accomplish it?

this is what it looks like when i print it it as it is.

how i want is author shows up first in the list not date. And I would like it alphabetical if possible and to remove the commas in the entrys to print it out cleaner. is it possible?

```
[[{'date': ['06-08-2012 09:01:52 PM'], 'path': [u'/branches/Patch_4_2_0_Branch'], 'msg': ['none', u'PATCH_BRANCH:N/A\nBUG_NUMBER:N/A\nFEATURE_AFFECTED:N/A\nOVERVIEW:N/A\nAdding the SVN log size requirement to the branch \n'], 'author': u'glv'}], [{'date': ['06-08-2012 09:01:52 PM'], 'path': [u'/branches/Patch_4_2_0_Branch'], 'msg': ['none', u'PATCH_BRANCH:N/A\nBUG_NUMBER:N/A\nFEATURE_AFFECTED:N/A\nOVERVIEW:N/A\nAdding the SVN log size requirement to the branch \n'], 'author': u'glv'}]]
```

Update: as of right now I can group the authors together but for some reason not only can't i get it alphebetized I cannot even get the author to be the first person on the list what shows up is something similar to this:

```
 Date: 06-08-2012 08:56:09 PM

  Changes by : glv

  Comments: PATCH_BRANCH:N/A BUG_NUMBER:N/A FEATURE_AFFECTED:N/A OVERVIEW:N/A Adding the svn commit line requrement  

            Directory Location: /trunk
```

The way i wanted it ordered is more like this.

```
  Changes by : glv
  Date: 06-08-2012 08:56:09 PM
  Directory Location: /trunk
  Comments: PATCH_BRANCH:N/A BUG_NUMBER:N/A FEATURE_AFFECTED:N/A OVERVIEW:N/A Adding the svn commit line requrement
```

I tried the OrderedList to see if I can get it to work that way but so far no luck or success. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: And a dict has no orderind unless you use OrderedDict class.

Comment: You do realise the `u`'s and commas are just part of the syntax to display a dictionary right? You're in charge of printing the elements how you want it...  Also - I can see a possible link to XML, but it's not used - and a single dict contains all author names etc... It would help - 1) format your code correctly and 2) show example data

Comment: You might consider using a class for `authorentry` instead of a dict and implementing the `__str__` method.

Comment: Which class would you suggest besides dict?  would you recommend collections?

Comment: Well thats just how I am taught to do I can post the whole code if you like. Its just very long, and not sure if it would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just care about presenting this information for user readability, use `pprint` module.

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(author)
```

assuming `author` is a `dict`. Alternatively use `pprint.pformat` to get a string which you can further manipulate/clean up e.g. `print pprint.pformat(author).replace(',','')` to remove commas.

You should also know that `dict`s can not be reordered since they are essentially a hashtable whos keys are hashes (like a set).

You can also try using `collections.OrdererdDict`:

```
from collections import OrdererdDict
sorted_author = OrderedDict(sorted(author.iteritems()))
```

---

**Update:** its strange you are still having problems with this. Ill just give you some code that will definitely work and you can adapt it from there:

```
def format_author(author):
    tups = sorted(author.iteritems())           # alphabetical sorting
    kmaxlen = max([len(k) for k, v in tups])    # for output alignment

    # some custom rearrangement. if there is a 'msg' key, we want it last
    tupkeys = [k for k, v in tups]
    if 'msg' in tupkeys:
        msg_tup = tups.pop(tupkeys.index('msg'))
        tups.append(msg_tup)    # append to the end
        # alternatively tups.insert(0, msg_tup) would insert at front

    output = []

    for k, v in tups:
        # dress our values
        if not v:
            v = ''
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            if len(v) == 1:
                v = v[0]
            if len(v) == 2 and v[0] in [None, 'none', 'None']:
                v = v[1]
         v = v.strip()
        output.append("%s: %s" % (k.rjust(kmaxlen), v))
    return "\n".join(output)
```

Then you can do something like:

```
author = {'date': ['06-08-2012 09:01:52 PM'], 'path': [u'/branches/Patch_4_2_0_Branch'], 'author': u'glv', 'msg': ['none', u'blah blah blah \n']}
s = format_author(author)
print s
```

and get output like this:

```
author: glv
  date: 06-08-2012 09:01:52 PM
  path: /branches/Patch_4_2_0_Branch
   msg: blah blah blah
```

Comment: Thank you, it is looking nicer. now I can just save it as a variable for later use for more formatting thank you. :)

Comment: Yes i did, I can see i can order them better that way. I am looking at the 8.3 collections page in the python docs to see how I can implement it into my code. Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you for showing me that it looks nicer. However for some reason it wants to sort the information through "date" rather then "author" or name is it possible to ask it to sort it out based on author or name?

Comment: Hey I have a question when I try to import OrderedDict it says I cannot import it for some odd reason. Why is that?

Comment: @GilbertLeeVera what version of Python are you using

Comment: I am using python 2.7.3, And I see your new example I will attempt to adopt it into my code. Looks very good I will check it out and give you feedback as soon as i am done thank you :)

Comment: Got an attribute error saying

    AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'strip'

doesn't look like i can use that attribute

Comment: seems like you have nested dictionaries. You can still use the above code but you will have to adapt it for nested inputs.

Comment: okay ,one way I tried around that error was to set up              #tups = str(sorted(author.iteritems())#

to see if it would help but now i get this error saying:

   -kmaxlen = max([len(k) for k, v in tups])-   
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: @GilbertLeeVera the code I posted above needs to be a dictionary of key value pairs. Right now it only supports leaf-level dicts (i.e. not nested dicts). It supports the kind of dict that I use as an example. If your data is structured differently you will have to adapt the code to fit your needs. But the example I posted above works with the data I use in my example.

Comment: Okay thank you, your example is appreciated and welcome. I will adapt the code to fit my needs and learn more because of it. thank you for giving me a map though to get better and learn more :)

Comment: Hey I got a question I was able to adapt the code. But I am wondering on something, author is now the second thing showing up on the list. I know you've showing the code how to make msg last. I am wondering if you could provide a hint or example on how to show author first if it is at all possible thank you.

Comment: @GilbertLeeVera `tups.insert(0, author_tup)` would insert it at front. However, author should not be coming second unless something is being inserted in front of it, or unless it is in fact 2nd in the lexicographic order of the keys (maybe there is leading whitespace in whatever key is coming first).

Answer (score 1):

You might consider creating a class for `authorentry` instead of using a dict and implementing the `__str__` method.

```
class authorentry:
    # create authorentry; usage: x = authorentry(author, date, path, msg)
    def __init__(self, author, date, path, msg):
        self.author = author
        self.date = date
        self.path = path
        self.msg = msg
    # return string representation for authorentry
    def __str__(self):
        return "Authorentry(name: %s, date: %r, path: ...)" % (self.author, self.date, ...)
```

Now you can create and print an `authorentry` like this:

```
ae = authorentry("some name", "some date", "some path", "some message")
print ae
```

Comment: Seems interesting, I have yet to actually create a class yet in python. I will do some research to see if i can implement it and use it to make my code better. Thank you.